# Agregar Publicidad Admob en app con Android Studio

Tags: java, android, admob

estoy intentando implementar publicidad a una aplicación pero no aparece cuando agrego el id que me da ADMOB y eso que seguí los pasos tal y como están en la pagina
https://developers.google.com/admob/android/quick-start
solo me aparece el banner pero con el id de prueba de ADMOB , por favor ayuda, llevo buscando alguna solución por un largo tiempo y nada...

Comment: Hola, Agrega el código que estas realizando, agrega mas detalles a tu pregunta, estas probando en un dispositio fisico o emulador?, revisa [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Inicializa AdMob en la actividad principal

```
    MobileAds.initialize(thisActivity, "xx-xxx-pub-0000000000000000/0000000000"); // 
    adView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
    AdRequest adReuest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
    adView.loadAd(adReuest);
```

Pero recuerda que también lo tienes que cambiar en `AndroidManifest.xml`

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
        android:value="xx-xxx-pub-0000000000000000/0000000000"/>
```